# How to fix Laravel HttpKernel\Exception error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I'm attempting a simple Ajax request however I get the following error message. What does this mean?

> {message: "", exception:
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…} exception:
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException" file:
>   "C:\MAMP\htdocs\project_21_my_laravel_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php"
>   line: 204 message: ""

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="myTestLink">my Test Link</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myTestLink").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'insert-ajax',
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::post('/insert-ajax', 'myTestController@testingsomething');
```

**myTestController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class myTestController extends Controller
{
    public function testingsomething()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `CSRF` token.

Please add the meta tag within the head tag in the blade file.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then change your javascript like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".myTestLink").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'insert-ajax',
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
                    },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });

        });
}
```

Comment: I had used that but still issue is there

Answer (score 1):

Please add the meta tag within the head tag in the blade file.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in the scripts section please add the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

For reference you can go through this the documentation [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token). Hope this helps and solves the issue. Thanks.